# Stop downloading jar form Repository Maven

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2, maven-3, xalan

In my Maven Project I have dependency for

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

But the downloaded jar is corrupted or it has problem so my application fails. I have a working jar in my hard. So I want to add that instead of downloading form repo. I used this to do that,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-xalan-2.7.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

But didn't work :(

Comment: why not remove the corrupted version from your local repository?

Comment: Yes a redoploy a correct version.

Comment: I have removed it from local repo and replaced it. But when I build it from another machine, same happens. So I wanted to ship my project with the jar included.